# how to export scala spark CrossValidatorModel to PMML?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, model, pmml

i have a problem about exporting my model to PMML.

my model used CrossValidatorModel to get best params.
but when i try to export my model to PMML that give me an error like this

```
value toPMML is not a member of org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidatorModel
```

so how to get the best model from crossValidatorModel and export to PMML.
in spark [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidatorModel) CVM not have .toPMML method.

spark 2.3.1 and scala 2.12.6

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [JPMML-SparkML](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sparkml) library.

Also available in the form of [`pyspark2pmml`](https://github.com/jpmml/pyspark2pmml) and [`sparklyr2pmml`](https://github.com/jpmml/sparklyr2pmml) packages.